# qichart and plotly making list instead of chart?

Tags: r, list, control-charts

I am currently following a tutorial to graph some data using qichart2. When I input the code, it creates a List instead of a graph. The same thing happened to me previously when I was trying to follow a plotly tutorial.

```
ControlChart <- qic(Force,
                    data = HudsonData,
                    chart = 'i',
                    title = NULL,
                    xlab  = NULL,
                    x = TimeStamp, 
                    ncol = 1,
                    show.labels = TRUE,
                    point.size = 3,
                    scales = "free_y",
                    facets = ~ Limb)
```

This creates a List of 9 instead of a plot like it did in the tutorial.

Is there something I have set up in my R Studio that is creating Lists instead of plots? When I use ggplot2 plots work fine.

Let me know if more info is needed that would be helpful.

Comment: What does `plot(ControlChart)` do?

Comment: Ohh interesting. It creates the plot! Why didn't it do that with the original code on its own?

Comment: That is interesting, because I don't need to do that on my R session. Running `example(qic)` plotted every time and doesn't use `plot()`. I get the plot when I type `qic(y)`.

Comment: Have you tried the software engineers' secret weapon? Shut down and restart R, preferably with an empty environment.

Comment: I started from scratch with empty scripts and environment and still had to do the plot(ControlChart) at the end to get the plot. Was hoping that would work!

I just did qic(y) and a plot came up right away though?

Comment: Maybe something in the tutorial messes with the graphics settings? If you restart from scratch again and don't do the tutorial, does `library(qicharts2)` then `example(qic)` work?

Comment: Yes that works. It created a y value and then gave me this message:

qic> # Lock random number generator to make reproducible results.

qic> set.seed(2)


qic> # Generate vector of 24 random normal numbers

qic> y <- rnorm(24)


qic> # Run chart
qic> qic(y)
Hit <Return> to see next plot:

Comment: Yep, that looks fine.The "hit return to see.." part is a system plotting option. It should reset to normal plotting behaviour after the example has run.